# Rails - best_In_place gem with date

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I'm trying to use the best_in_place gem with type => date , but I'm having some problems with the format. My rails date format is as follows:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({:default => '%d %b (%a)'})
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({:default => '%d %b (%a)'})
```

And in my view I have:

```
<%= best_in_place @group, :appearance_time ,:type => :date %>
```

Now when the page is loaded the first time, the date is in the rails format, however when I change it with jquery, it goes back to the format "dd/mm/yy" .. I tried changing the format like this:

```
jQuery ->
   $.extend($.fn.datepicker.defaults, { format: 'dd M D' });
```

But it doesn't change anything.. How can I set the jquery date format?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out in case anyone else has the same problem.

Jquery:

```
jQuery ->
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'dd M (D)' });
```

It needs to be called before your code.